# How to convert scanned pdf to text files in a directory more efficiently using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ocr, python-tesseract

I use the following code to convert all scanned pdf files in a directory into text files. However, currently, I get one text file for each pdf page. For instance, I get multiple text files such as `examplepage1.txt` `examplepage2.txt` from `example.pdf`. Is there any way I could combine text files for all the pages from one pdf? This way I could create just one text file per pdf. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
import pytesseract
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import glob

pdfs = glob.glob(r"K:\pdfs\*.pdf")

for pdf_path in pdfs:
    pages = convert_from_path(pdf_path, 500)

    for pageNum,imgBlob in enumerate(pages):
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(imgBlob,lang='eng')

        with open(f'{pdf_path[:-4]}_page{pageNum}.txt', 'w') as the_file:
            the_file.write(text)
```

**UPDATE:**
Upon the suggestion in the comment, I have made the following changes and it is working fine now. It creates one text per scanned pdf.

```
import pytesseract
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import glob

pdfs = glob.glob(r"K:\pdfs\*.pdf")

for pdf_path in pdfs:
    pages = convert_from_path(pdf_path, 500)

    for pageNum,imgBlob in enumerate(pages):
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(imgBlob,lang='eng')

        with open(f'{pdf_path}.txt', 'a') as the_file:
            the_file.write(text)
```

Comment: Try `with open("one-filename", "a")` instead of "w". Mode "a" means add. Note you can change filename.

Comment: I get the same result, that is, one text file per page.

Comment: Did you set the only one filename? In your code, it seems filename is changing with page.

Comment: Yes, It is working now. Thank you so much. You could write the code here so that I could upvote.

Comment: Good to hear that. This was a typical and easy question, so it's ok to close only comments here.